# Insert List<string> into word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm currently trying to find a way to read in, and insert data into a word document.  So far this is what I have gotten:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var FileName = @"C:\temp\test.DOC";
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        Application app = new Application();
        Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\test.DOC");

        foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in doc.Paragraphs)
        {
            data.Add(objParagraph.Range.Text.Trim());
        }
        //data.Insert


        data.Insert(16, "Test 1");
        data.Insert(16, "\tTest 2\tName\tAmount");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 3");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 4");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 5");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 6");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 7");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 8");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 9");
        data.Insert(16, "Test 10");

        var x = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
        x.Range.Text.Insert(0,"\tTest 2\tName\tAmount");

        doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\temp\test3.DOC");

        ((_Document)doc).Close();
        ((_Application)app).Quit();

    }
}
```

Now, this successfully populates the List data - but I'm trying to append each new test element at the [16]th index, and save it into the word document.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this, or am I just over-thinking this issue?

I realize the string list is separate from the Document object which represents the word document.

I have a few other places in the document where I am using bookmarks to add data, but I don't think it is possible to use bookmarks for placing the data in this instance - or If I don't have to use bookmarks I'd like to stray away from that.

EDIT: I am trying to insert X amount of elements at the [16]th position within the data[].

EDIT 2:
Essentially I am sourcing the data dynamically, and I'm not sure how many records/rows I'll need to add to the document, so it could be as follows:

```
[15]
[16]\tName\tID\tAMOUNT
[17]\tName\tID\tAMOUNT
[18]\tName\tID\tAMOUNT
```

Since the headers will already be there (NAME,ID,AMOUNT), and each time I run the program I'm not sure how many elements I'll be inserting into the document - so as long as each element is placed under one another, and on the 16th line in the document template I have setup that should accomplish what I am trying to do.

Image 1 - Image into string array
Image 2 - Image after adding content into the string - this is what the resulting document. (this is to be saved)

[image: Image into string array]
[image: Image after adding content into the string - this is what the resulting document]

[image]
I'm attempting to put each element ie: Test1    Test2    Test3 in their each own column each (see above)

Comment: It is not clear from your post what exactly you are wanting to accomplish. _I'm trying to append each new test element at the [16]th index, and save it into the word document_... ???

Comment: Added a bit to improve clarity - did that help?  I am just trying to add each element of a List<string> to a specific index and append it to the word document at a specific position.

Comment: @JohnG Yeah I essentially want to add each element of the data list to line [16] in the document and save it.

The goal is to just add each element of the string list onto a new line within the document at line [16] with a tab character inbetween each item to create "columns" of sorts.  Much like: "\tTest 2\tName\tAmount

Comment: @JohnG I can't share the original - Basically the original document has a total of 42 lines, and the header row is on line 15 of the document (data<list>) 

So, if data contains 5 elements - I'm trying to insert each element onto the 16th line in the document.  (So each new line will be pushed down one - adding a new line to the document so in this example I would end with 47 lines.

Comment: If you cant share the original... make up a test one so we can see what you have to start with. When you say _So, if data contains 5 elements..._ this wont happen if the original document has 42 lines... you are reading each line in the original document and putting the string into the list data. This is confusing. Also I am going to delete my previous comments.

Comment: I'll create a test document to post in a few hours - thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: @JohnG I have updated the question with two photos after reading in the document before adding elements to the document and after.

Comment: List<T>.InsertRange(16, [your list])?

Comment: @Dmitry That would correctly populate the List<T> with the elements, but I'm trying to populate the word document structure with the List<T>.  Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again I am totally confused as to why you want to read the word file into a string list array. This simply adds the text you show after line 15 into the word document. You do not specify WHERE Test 1, Test 2, Test3... are coming from.

**Edit:** Added a try-catch just in case the document does not have at least 16 paragraphs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  List<string> data = new List<string>();
  Application app = new Application();
  Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\test.DOC");

  string testRows = "Test 1\n\tTest 2\tName\tAmount\nTest 3\nTest 4\nTest 5\nTest 6\nTest 7\nTest 8\nTest 9\nTest 10\n";

  try
  {
    var x = doc.Paragraphs[16];
    x = doc.Paragraphs.Add(x.Range);
    x.Range.Text = testRows;
    doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\temp\test3.DOC");
  }
  catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("COMException: " +  e.StackTrace.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
  ((_Document)doc).Close();
  ((_Application)app).Quit();

}
```

Comment: Added an "Edit 2" for more clarification.

Comment: Test 1, 2 3, etc are coming from a separate system, so I can put them into a list to use them.  The only reason I was reading in the whole file because I was trying to see which index to place the text at.  I have added a new image to explain further.

Comment: In short - Instead of working with lines of text (while it may be helpful to understand the structure of the document) the way you did it is far superior .  I'll post an answer with my exact code and explain  - Thanks for all the help John!

Comment: @confusedandamused... glad this helped. I added a try catch just in case the document does not have 16 paragraphs.

Comment: I posted my answer as well to what I accomplished - thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So what I figured out (for my purposes) is that is is easiest to insert a list of strings into makeshift columns separated by tabs by inserting at specific paragraphs.

Since I am using bookmarks to place text as well - I found it useful to work from a copy of a document instead of worrying about removing/creating bookmarks each time.

When populating the list that you are going to be placing at a specific paragraph mark it is useful to append tab characters as well as newline charters on the fly.  Later on this will make it easier to loop through the list and place them nicely on the document.

Depending on the way you are going to go about placing columns some logic will have to be determined to space everything correctly.  I did this by creating maximum lengths for columns and trimming, and accommodating for smaller/larger lengths by adding specific amounts of tab characters.

So, my columns I am populating would look like:

```
myList.Add("\t12345678912345\tJohn Doe\t\t\t\t123456\r\n");
myList.Add("\987654321654987\tJohn Smith\t\t\t\98765\r\n");
```

These lines would be inserted at paragraph 17 and placed neatly under headers.

Lastly, I decided to use bookmarks to place single lines of text like the date,title, and signature values since those values don't need to be correctly spaced or anything.

At the end I delete the copy of the word document I'm working on, and delete the pdf (since in my case I'm sending it via email)

Thank you for the help @JohnG - I hope this answer might help others who come across it.  I removed the try-catch since I'm working from the template as well.

```
File.Copy(sCurrentPath + "\\" + "testTemplate.DOC", sCurrentPath + "\\" + "test.DOC");

Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Add(sCurrentPath + "\\" + "test.DOC");

foreach (string sValue in myList)
{
    var List = doc.Paragraphs[17];
    myList = doc.Paragraphs.Add(myList.Range);
    myList.Range.Text = sValue;
}

if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("Date"))
{
    object oBookMark = "Date";
    doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("Signature"))
{
    object oBookMark = "Signature";
    doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = "My Name";
}
if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("Title"))
{
    object oBookMark = "Title";
    doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = "Title Here";
}

doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(sCurrentPath + "\\" + "test.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

File.Delete(sCurrentPath + "\\" + "testCopy.DOC");

File.Delete(sCurrentPath + "\\" + "test.pdf");

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)app).Quit();
```